# And a wall divides them all

Tags: riddle

We are all cut by it
It protected but also hurt
It crumbles now in its old age
And its stones are of some homes
Eight of us form the group. 
It excluded of course. 
Igianugi is our name when our ends meet. 
Who is it and who are we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> The Great Wall of China

and you are

> Beijing, Gansu, Hebei, Liaoning, Ningxia, Shaanxi, Shanxi and Tianjin

We are all cut by it
It protected but also hurt
It crumbles now in its old age
And its stones are of some homes

> The Great Wall passes through several provinces, it used to protect them from raids but also hurt trade. It's crumbling now in most places, some of the raw materials have been used to build houses.

Eight of us form the group.
It excluded of course.
Igianugi is our name when our ends meet.

> The eight provinces the Great Wall passes through. Pick the last letter of each, shuffle.